# Select last set of records in sql group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Orable database with a table like follows:

```
ID  PROVIDER_ID FROM_CURRENCY   TO_CURRENCY         DATE    AMOUNT  ACTIVE  
1             1           USD           EUR    06-FEB-19      1.23     1
2             2           USD           EUR    06-FEB-19       1.5     1
3             1           GBP           EUR    06-FEB-19      1.23     1
4             1           CAD           EUR    06-FEB-19      1.23     1
5             1           USD           EUR    05-FEB-19       0.7     1
6             1           GBP           EUR    05-FEB-19       0.7     1
```

As you can see, we store exchange rates from different providers with its date, and what I need is to get the IDs of the latest available rates for a specific `to_currency` (eg. EUR) and `provider_id` (eg. 1) at a certain date. So I should get something like follows:

```
ID
1
3
4
```

Please be aware that DATE is not unique so values can be duplicated among different rows and I can not use it to join with a subquery. Also, consider that DATE and ID are not correlated, so higher dates don't necessarily mean higher IDs (I cannot just use `MAX(ID)` in the select clause to get the ID of the target row).

I have tried with the following query, but I get an error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

```
SELECT ID 
FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND PROVIDER_ID = 1 AND TO_CURRENCY = 'EUR' AND DATE <= TO_DATE('2019-02-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY PROVIDER_ID, FROM_CURRENCY, TO_CURRENCY
HAVING DATE = MAX(DATE)
```

I've also tried the following query with the same error:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DATE)
FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND PROVIDER_ID = 1 AND TO_CURRENCY = 'EUR' AND DATE <= TO_DATE('2019-02-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY PROVIDER_ID, FROM_CURRENCY, TO_CURRENCY
```

The query that retrieves the rows I need is the following one, but I don't know how to obtain the ID field for these rows since ID is not part of the group by clause.

```
SELECT MAX(DATE)
FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND PROVIDER_ID = 1 AND TO_CURRENCY = 'EUR' AND DATE <= TO_DATE('2019-02-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY PROVIDER_ID, FROM_CURRENCY, TO_CURRENCY
```

Any idea about how can achieve what I need?

**EDIT**
I think I've found a solution

```
SELECT ID
FROM EXCHANGE_RATE E JOIN
  (SELECT PROVIDER_ID, FROM_CURRENCY, TO_CURRENCY, MAX(DATE) AS LATEST
    FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
    WHERE DATE <= TO_DATE('2019-02-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    GROUP BY PROVIDER_ID, FROM_CURRENCY, TO_CURRENCY) LATEST_EX
  ON E.PROVIDER_ID = LATEST_EX.PROVIDER_ID
  AND E.TO_CURRENCY = LATEST_EX.TO_CURRENCY
  AND E.FROM_CURRENCY = LATEST_EX.FROM_CURRENCY
  AND E.DATE = LATEST_EX.LATEST
WHERE E.ACTIVE = 1 AND E.PROVIDER_ID = 1 AND E.TO_CURRENCY = 'EUR'
```

Answer (score 2):

user `row_number()` function to rank the dates in descending order for each currency

```
SELECT id
FROM
  (SELECT id, provider_id, from_Currency,
          row_number() over 
          ( partition by from_Currency order by "DATE" desc ) as rn
     FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
  )
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: thanks for the edit ,, wrote in a hurry forgot () after row_number#

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to write a stored proc to hold the data row returned by the final query and get the Id by fetching the pointer for that in the table.

```
SELECT MAX(DATE)
FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND PROVIDER_ID = 1 AND TO_CURRENCY = 'EUR' AND DATE <= TO_DATE('2019-02-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY PROVIDER_ID, FROM_CURRENCY, TO_CURRENCY
```

Apart from this, the only way to get the ID return from single query is to use that in group by but i dont see that will solve the purpose, the subquery will not work as well as mentioned by you.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery

```
SELECT ID
  FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
WHERE ("DATE") IN
(
SELECT MAX("DATE")
  FROM EXCHANGE_RATE
 WHERE ACTIVE = 1 
   AND PROVIDER_ID = 1 
   AND TO_CURRENCY = 'EUR' 
 )
   AND ACTIVE = 1 
   AND PROVIDER_ID = 1 
   AND TO_CURRENCY = 'EUR'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/YUWUX64337)</kbd>

Comment: I think you're missing a point, what I need is to get every latest combination for (provider_id, from_currency, to_currency) but the subquery in your answer will only return one result containing the row with the max the between all those that match the where clause.

Comment: @beni0888 the subquery already satisfies all the required conditions. I added the demo.

Comment: It works just because of a coincidence in the data set. Try changing the date of the fourth row (CAD, EUR) to a day before `2019-02-05` and you'll see that it's not included in the result, and that's something possible. But thanks anyway for your effort proposing a solution with an example :)

Comment: @beni0888 welcome. In that case ID 1 and 3 return, ok, but don't you need the last date for 1,1,'EUR' ? Without considering the date already 1,3,4,5,6 would return.

Comment: Barbaros, I'm not saying you shouldn't consider the date, just pointing out that the solution you propose doesn't achieve what I looking for. I need to retrieve the latest row for every (provider_id, from_currency, to_currency) regardless of the difference in dates between them.